# How to add attribute to a node in networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I have 2 files. The first file has the edges and the weight and has the following format:

```
1    3     1
2    4     1
2    5     1 etc
```

and the second file has the node id and the atrributes of the node:

```
1    attr1,attr2,attr3
2    attr2,attr4
```

Using the first file i create the directed graph using the following code:

```
G = nx.read_edgelist('myGraph.txt', create_using=nx.DiGraph(), delimiter='\t', nodetype=int, data=(('sign', int),))
```

And next i use the second file to read each line. I read the first token(node id), i check if this node belongs to my graph nodes and then i use again the split function to remove the commas. Now i want to save the attributes to node. I use the following code but the attributes remain blank. Here is my code:

```
for line in file2:
    words = line.split()
    node = words[0]
    attributes = words[1]
    splittedAttributes  = attributes.split(',')
    G.node[node]['Attributes'] = splittedAttributes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little mistake in your code:

```
G = nx.read_edgelist('myGraph.txt', create_using=nx.DiGraph(), delimiter='\t', nodetype=int, data=(('sign', int),))
```

`nodetype=int` you are loading nodes as `int`. Because `line` is a `str` then `node` is a `str` too. If you want to work with `ints` then do the following:

```
node = int(words[0])
```

That should do the trick. Remember to access the attributes as `G.node[node]['Attributes']` and not as `G[node]['Attributes']` because that would output the weight of nodes `node` and `Attributes` which should throw an error.